# Passing data backward without using a segue?

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, segue, protocols

I didn't use a `storyboard`, how could I pass data backward programmatically without using a segue in `Xcode 4.2` ?

I had tried on creating a segue programmatically (to pass data backward via delegate and protocols) but I was stuck...Because it includes an identifier name for a segue...

I'm coding my app without using a storyboard...

```
    @objc func getWeatherTapped() {

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        guard let destinationViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "") as? WeatherViewController else {

            print("Couldn't find the viewController")

            return

        present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How could I fix this? Any help?

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: use delegation pattern

Comment: When loading/presenting the view controller, you need to seed it with a delegate (custom protocol) which is notified just before you dismiss the current view controller

Comment: You need `Delegation Pattern` . I still wonder why you need _an identifier name for a segue_ while using _delegate and protocol_

Comment: @SPatel: I did :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you tell me more about it ?  I'm a self-taught coder :)

Comment: @ShubhamBaksh: so there's a way you don't need an identifier name for a segue while using delegate and protocols? I've never heard of it before can you tell me more about it? :)

Comment: Okay, Tell me how are you going from FirstVC to SecondVC in the first place ? If you're not using storyboard, then you must be using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` . Or is there any other thing you're using?

Comment: See , if you're _going back_ to a View Controller this is already in your hierarchy , then you dont need an _identifier_, you just dismiss the ViewController and call the delegate method in which you _pass the data as parameter_ . If you're adding a new View Controller to you hierarchy , then you need to instantiate and then you need an identifier :)

Comment: @KimPage Define a protocol which allows data to be passed through it, in the source VC, conform to the protocol, in the destination VC, define a delegate var of the type of protocol, before pushing the destination VC, set the delegate of destination to reference the source VC. When popping the destination VC, pass what ever you need back through the delegate

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi: Because of passing data backward, I need to set FirstVC as the delegate. Here what I set FirstVC as the delegate:                                                                                     
 let secondVC = SecondVC() /   secondVC.delegate = self ... it didn't work!!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Please tell me more about setting the delegate of destination to reference the source VC. Here what I set FirstVC as the delegate: let secondVC = SecondVC() / secondVC.delegate = self ... it didn't work!!! –

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating a `protocol` which defines the actions/operations you want to allow...

```
protocol DataPassingDelegate {
    var someReallyImportantData: String { get set } // Or what ever type
}
```

In your destination controller define a property of the `protocol` type...

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    var dataPassingDelegate: DataPassingDelegate?
    //...
}
```

In the source view controller, conform to the `DataPassingDelegate` `protocol`

```
class SourceViewController: UIViewController, DataPassingDelegate {
    var someReallyImportantData: String = "" {
        didSet {
            // Update if you need to or simply
            // check the state in viewWillAppear
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Before you push the destination view controller, from the source controller, set the delegate...

```
destinationViewController.dataPassingDelegate = self
present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Before you pop the destination view controller, pass the data back...

```
dataPassingDelegate = "I have something to say"
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
// or if you're using a navigation controller
// navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I don't use navigationController is that okay?

Comment: Makes no difference, wasn't sure which dismissal approach you were using

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough!!! All the best things in the world for you in the future :)))

Comment: Better define the delegate as `weak`.

Comment: @MuhammedGül Well, sure, that would logical, except, Swing says *"'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'DataPassingDelegate'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound"* :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer Make protocol subclass of "class". `protocol DataPassingDelegate : class { ... }`